# React - Table rows only render after unrelated function call

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a weird bug that I've been trying to debug for a few hours now but just can't seem to figure it out. Essentially my table rows won't render unless a function that calls `setState` is run.

My table is formatted like so:

```
<table classname="ui inverted table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Lobby name</th>
      <th>Players</th>
      <th>Mode</th>
      <th>Difficulty</th>
      <th>Status</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    {this.renderRow()} //Table rows
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The rows are rendered by this function, that maps over an array of objects:

```
renderRow = () => {
    return games.map(function(val, i){
         return(
             <tr key={i}>
                 <td>
                     {val.name}
                 </td>
                 <td>
                     {val.currentPlayers}/4
                 </td>
                 <td>
                     {val.gameMode}
                 </td>
                 <td>
                     {val.difficulty}
                 </td>
             </tr>
         )
     })
 }
```

Now here is the weird bug. The rows won't render unless I tap a button which calls `createGame`. The only thing `createGame` does is: `this.setState({show: true})`

The Menu is:

```
<div classname="ui inverted segment">
  <div classname="ui large inverted pointing secondary menu">
    <button classname="active item">
      Lobby
    </button>
    <div classname="ui right inverted pointing secondary menu">
      <button classname="item menu_item" onclick={this.createGame}>
        //Have to click this button to render rows for some reason.
        <i classname="plus circle icon"></i>
        Create Game
      </button>
      <div classname="item">
        <img classname="ui mini circular image" src={this.state.photoURL}></img>
        <span classname="menu_name">{this.state.userName}</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CreateGame for reference as well:

```
createGame = () => {
   this.setState({show: true})
};
```

It seems like it's really the `show` attribute in state that's triggering the table rows for some reason, but it's not being conditionally rendered so I don't understand why triggering that state param would cause the rendering. If I manually set `show: true` in React devtools the table rows render as well.

EDIT: `games` is being populated like so:

```
componentDidMount(){
             //DB listner, gets all games on component mount, and all new games. 
             db.collection("games")
             .onSnapshot(function(querySnapshot){
                 querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc){
                     games.push(doc.data())
                 });
                 console.log(games);
             });
}
```

Comment: we will need some more of the code. for example, how is the renderRow function accessing the games array? is it getting passed in? how is it in scope?

Comment: I'm thinking it's not rendering because renderRow was not completed during the first render cycle.

Comment: games is declared as a global variable outside the class.

Comment: how is games being set. maybe it starts off as as an empty array then gets populated some how when you click the button and invoke the createGame function.

Comment: I've added an edit. The function that populates games is just calling db api and populating the array.

Comment: Sidenote: Do not use index as element keys. Indexes might change due to inserts, deletes or sorting, resulting in weird rendering issues.

Comment: Why not set result as state after retrieving from db and use that state to render rows instead?

Comment: yes what @ShawnYap said. also how is games being initilazed if its not in state? are you setting it in the constructor this.games = ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `componentDidMount` is only called **after** the first rendering, your table rows will not be rendered initially. The games array is empty at this point.

It would make sense to move `games` into the component state here. Thereby automatically updating the state, once the games have been loaded. Remember, a setState will usually trigger a re-render.

```
componentDidMount(){

  //DB listner, gets all games on component mount, and all new games. 
  db.collection("games").onSnapshot(function(querySnapshot) {

    const loadedGames = querySnapshot.map(function(doc) {
      return doc.data();
    });

    // update the state
    this.setState({ games: loadedGames });

  });

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. This seems to work, but how would I map over this.state.games? Replacing games with this.state.games in my renderRow func doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Could be a bind issue. Check that you actually have the right `this` and access to the state object. Often just adding a couple of `console.log` statements helps.